# Django models class method appears not to sort a list of objects containing itself, advice?

Tags: python, django

In a Django UserProfile model, I am trying to do the following:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):

  ...

  def recent_activity(self):
    followed_users = Followed.objects.filter(user=self.id).order_by("-when")
    ...

    items = [self]
    for f in followed_users:
      items.append(f)

    ...

    sorted(items,key=lambda item: item.getDate)

    return items[:7]
```

The code is supposed to return a user's "recent activity" by pulling together a number of different actions they can do and then sorting them by date.

Each model implements a "getDate" method which returns the date to sort by.

The code:

1. Gets a QuerySet of users that the user has "followed" (I am using a table called Followed to store the fact that user x follows user y).
2. Creates a list containing the UserProfile object in question.
3. Add each Followed object to the list.
4. Sort the list by the last edit date.
5. Return the most recent n items (7 in the above).

I thought this was a neat way of implementing it. But no matter what I do, Python seems to refuse the correctly sort that list. It seems to sort *every* type of recent activity correctly except for the UserProfile - which seems to stay wherever I originally put it in that list after calling `sorted`. It doesn't fail in any way, it just doesn't return a correctly sorted list!

I've probably missed something simple... but I would expect either Python to complain that an object's method cannot sort a list that contains the object itself, OR for the list to be correctly sorted. I was a bit surprised that it did neither.

Can anyone tell me where I've gone astray?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that `sorted` does *not* sort in-place.

You have probably read that `list.sort()` *does* sort in-place. But `sorted()` actually returns the sorted list - but you are not assigning it to anything, so it just gets thrown away. Either use `sort()`, or assign the result to something.

(Plus, you'll need to actually call `getDate`, as Marcin points out.)

Comment: Thank you. This was the solution. Nice that it was so "obvious".

Thanks also for the comments regarding `getDate()`.

Answer (score 1):

(1) The problem is that `item.getDate` will return the function (or rather, bound method) object `getDate`, and not a date. Change that to `item.getDate()`, or use `key=Followed.getDate` if `self` is an instance of `Followed`.

(2) There is no need to use a loop to convert a queryset to a list. Just use:

```
items = [self] + list(followed_users)
```

(This does create an unnecessary list. Because you can turn any iterable into a list, if you wanted to avoid that, you could use itertools.chain to create a single iterable to turn into a list).

Comment: Thank you - but:

1. The first solution doesn't work. It still correctly sorts all items **except** for the `UserProfile` object, but simply has no effect on the UserProfile object. `sorted` seems not to mind therefore whether I use a bound method or a date? I assume this means the method does get correctly called. I still see the same behaviour whether I use `getDate` or `getDate()`. `self` is not an instance of `Followed` - but it does implement `getDate()`
2. I did this because I _actually_ needed to filter what gets added. Is there a way of doing the above with some kind of filter?

Comment: @JonathanMay: (1) TO be clear, I am recommending that you do `key=lambda item: item.getDate()`, if you have not tried that. (2) If you did try that, then I suggest that there is a problem with `getDate`, either in all of your objects, or just in the one that is not being sorted. (3) Have you tried `filter` or `itertools.ifilter`?

Comment: Thank you for your help - I did try this - it just wasn't the main thing that was breaking my solution in the end - just one of two problems. Much appreciated for your help.